# Recursive copy files in bash preserving dir tree

Tags: bash, tree, copy

My application X organizes projects in folders with a specific tree. The first level of the tree is defined (hard constraint), while all the contents are freely organized.

My goal is to iterate over all folders of the project tree, parse folder names to get targets based on conditions, then copy the selected targets to a new project folder, keeping the tree structure, so that application X is not going to complain.

So far, I've come up with this:

```
cp -pr `find . -type d | grep -i targetstring` ../newProjectFolder/
```

This has issues: 1) it doesn't preserve folder tree; 2) throws a lot of errors `cp: cannot stat` (see also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34254164/what-is-cp-cannot-stat-error-in-unix-i-get-this-error-when-trying-to-copy-thin)). It isn't just working as intended.

Moreover, parsing the output of `find` is [generally a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6833627/2125110).

I was able to overcome first problem with `--parents` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1650164/bash-copy-named-files-recursively-preserving-folder-structure). However, I'm copying way less than what I need due to point 2, so not a solution after all.

<strike>*I am looking for a one-liner solution to the problem*</strike>. Script based solution is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513734/shell-copying-directories-recursively-with-regex-matching-preserving-tree-stru). **EDIT:** as this was marked as duplicated of the link provided, I'll rephrase a little: I want a solution where I don't need to explicitly while and if-else my way to it. Piping `find` and `grep` provides all the locations to be copied, but `cp` is complaining. How do we feed them to `cp`, without it complaining?

I was looking for something using `-exec` as suggersted [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/83593/copy-specific-file-type-keeping-the-folder-structure), and came up with the following, which is not working <strike>(nothing gets copied)</strike> (only partial tree structure is copied, and files inside that structure are only copied if they match the regex as well):

```
find . -regex ".*targetstring.*" -exec cp -rp --parents \{\} ../newProjectFolder \;
```

Comment: Duplicate of: [Shell - copying directories recursively with RegEx matching preserving tree structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50513734/shell-copying-directories-recursively-with-regex-matching-preserving-tree-stru). *I am looking for a one-liner solution to the problem.* remove linebreaks and boom, it's a one liner

Comment: Yeah, ok, everything is a one-liner that way, even a script where I use nested loops over loops. Is there a way to achieve this without looping and if-elsing my way, calling simple, made-to-purpose software pieces?

Comment: Not that I know of. Try your chance at [softwarerecs.se]

Answer (score 2):

**"one-liner" but `sed` will not work for newlines `$'\n'` in filename**

assuming you `cd` into project folder and run `find .` always with `.`
it will match *targetstring* (on any level) and will copy the whole (containing) tree from **first level**

**example tree**
`searchProjectFolder/some/parent/folders/matched/targetstring/foo/bar/`

a search for `*targetstring*` inside `searchProjectFolder/` will copy whole `./some` folder (including all files and subfolders)

while `-regex` or `-ipath` will print all files, `-iname` will only print the matching folder `targetstring/` itself. you can limit search to specific level(s) with `-mindepth 5` and `-maxdepth 5`, and specify the target type to match *folders* only with `-type d` (but let us take away this options for now)

**create newProjectFolder and run find on example tree**

```
mkdir newProjectFolder
cd searchProjectFolder
find . -iname "*targetstring*"
```

result on example tree is

```
./some/parent/folders/matched/targetstring
```

**now `find` result is piped to `grep` so we can cut the string to first level only**

```
find . -iname "*targetstring*" | grep -o ^\./[^/]*
```

result on example tree is

```
./some
```

**instead of `grep` we can use `sed` to quote the "folder name" (may have spaces)**

```
find . -iname "*targetstring*" | sed -n 's,^\(\./[^/]*\).*,"\1",p'
```

result on example tree is

```
"./some"
```

**finally let's `cp` all folders with `eval` because "folder names" are quoted. this is the "one-liner":**

```
eval cp -a $(find . -iname "*targetstring*" | sed -n 's,^\(\./[^/]*\).*,"\1",p') ../newProjectFolder
```

result on example tree is

```
cp -a "./some" ../newProjectFolder
```

**for better understanding i will explain the sed**

```
sed -n 's,^\(\./[^/]*\).*,"\1",p'
sed -n 's, ^  \(  \.  /  [^/]*  \)  .* , "\1" ,p'
```

`-n` = do not print input
p in `,p'` = print only matching output

`\1` = print the first capture group
`\(` = begin of capture group
`\)` = end of capture group

`^` = match begin of string only
`\.` = single dot (`.`)
`/` = single slash (path delimiter)
`[^/]` = any single byte, but not a slash
`[^/]*` = any string not containing slashes
`.` = single byte
`.*` = any string

so the (first) capture group is (begin of line)
`./example string`

the capture group is quoted (`"\1"`)
`"./example string"`

---

edit:

**another "real" one-liner if you only want to copy folder `targetstring/` (with parent tree)**

```
mkdir newProjectFolder
cd searchProjectFolder
find . -iname "*targetstring*" -exec cp -a --parents {} ../newProjectFolder \;
```

result on example tree is

```
cp -a --parents "./some/parent/folders/matched/targetstring" ../newProjectFolder
```

Comment: which folder do you want to copy? `./some/parent/folders/matched/targetstring/foo/bar/`

Comment: `find . -iname "*targetstring*" -exec cp -a --parents {} ../newProjectFolder \;` does only copy folder *"targetstring"* (with tree) - i guess you want copy whole folder *"some"*?

Comment: I actually like this very much! For once, it has no while loops with if conditions, and uses piece of software as they are intended to. I want to copy only `targetstring/` and all its content, keeping the tree rooting at `some/`. Say some has also a folder `parent2/` and none of the children of `parent2/` match, then `parent2/` shall not be copied. Rinse and repeat at all levels.

Comment: then you already have had the solution yourself, just replace `-regex` with `-iname` (see my last comment)