# bash: How do I selectively copy directories from one tree to another?

Tags: bash

My directory tree looks somewhat like this:

```
/Volumes/Data/TEMP/DROP
├───R1
│   ├───morestuff
│   │   └───stuff2
│   │       └───C.tool
│   └───stuff
│       ├───A.tool
│       └───B.Tool
└───R2
    ├───morestuff
    │   └───stuff2
    │       └───C.tool
    └───stuff
        ├───A.tool
        └───B.Tool
```

How do I copy the `*.tool` directories recursively from `R1` to (overwrite) those in `R2`? My bash has about 20 years of rust on it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61104639/recursive-copy-files-in-bash-preserving-dir-tree see the edit-part on my answer `find /Volumes/Data/TEMP/DROP/R1 -type d -iname "*.tool" -exec cp -a --parents {} /Volumes/Data/TEMP/DROP/R2 \;`

Comment: Use `rsync` with an exclude filter, see http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html#INCLUDE/EXCLUDE_PATTERN_RULES

Answer (score 1):

This will work (expanding on the idea of @Maxim Egorushkin)

```
# The trailing slash important in the next line
SOURCE=/Volumes/Data/TEMP/DROP/R1/
DEST=/Volumes/Data/TEMP/DROP/R2
rsync -zarv --include "*/" --include="*.tool" --exclude="*" "$SOURCE" "$DEST"
```